# Sencha Touch Not Grouping TableView

Tags: sencha-touch

Anyways, I am trying to do a simple grouped tableview and it is not working in Sencha. It shows all the items together without adding a grouping.

Here is the complete code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.CompletedList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    alias: 'widget.CompletedList',
    fullscreen:true,
    grouped:true,
    ui:'round',
    requires: [
        'Ext.dataview.List'
    ],
    config:{

        fullscreen:true,
        grouped:true,
        store: {
            fields: ['name', 'league', 'division'],
            sorters: 'name',
            grouper: {
                groupFn: function (item) {
                    return item.get('league') + ' ' + item.get('division');
                }
            },
            data: [
            {
                name: 'Texas',
                league: 'AL',
                division: 'West'
            },
            {
                name: 'Boston',
                league: 'AL',
                division: 'East'
            },
            {
                name: 'California',
                league: 'AL',
                division: 'West'
            },
            {
                name: 'Costa Rica',
                league: 'AL',
                division: 'East'
            },
            {
                name: 'Seattle',
                league: 'AL',
                division: 'East'
            }] 
        },
        itemTpl:'{name}' 
    }
});
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: your code works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me (Touch 2.3.x)... have you run "sencha app build" or "sencha ant sass" to update your theme and other resources?

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    fullscreen:true,
    grouped:true,
    store: {
        fields: ['name', 'league', 'division'],
        sorters: 'name',
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (item) {
                return item.get('league') + ' ' + item.get('division');
            }
        },
        data: [
        {
            name: 'Texas',
            league: 'AL',
            division: 'West'
        },
        {
            name: 'Boston',
            league: 'AL',
            division: 'East'
        },
        {
            name: 'California',
            league: 'AL',
            division: 'West'
        },
        {
            name: 'Costa Rica',
            league: 'AL',
            division: 'East'
        },
        {
            name: 'Seattle',
            league: 'AL',
            division: 'East'
        }] 
    },
    itemTpl:'{name}'
});
```

Comment: No I have not run it! I noticed that the problem was the style injected by Sencha. x-list-header with display:none. Not sure why they would do that. I changed the style and now it works. The app is not running iOS 6 theme and not iOS 7.

Comment: Glad it helped! Recompiling your CSS is usually the first thing I'd try :-) All sorts of issues like this might happen.